# Age vs. Receptiveness to propaganda/ ideology

Tags: social-psychology, political-psychology

I am interested in the relation between the age of an individual and their receptiveness towards propaganda or ideology.

I would suspect that children/adolescents are strongly receptive towards propaganda and that as they enter adulthood they become less receptive.

Are there any studies on this that verify my claim/ contradict it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Psychology.SE.

This has the potential to be a very big subject, depending on how deep you want to go into it. You may wish to look at [priming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) along with studies surrounding [conformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformity) and peer pressure, looking at how they play a part in early behaviour and belief forming.

You may also want to look at [Ron Jones' "Third Wave" Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Wave_(experiment)) which was portrayed in the movie called [*The Wave*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1063669/)